# Wi-Fi enabled ODBII Script

Tags: python, wifi, c++, cars

I have a Wi-Fi enabled OBDII dongle for my car and want to connect it to my Pi to log diagnostics. I can find libraries and information for USB and Bluetooth OBDII adapters, but can't find anything about using Wi-Fi adapters.

Does anyone know how to use Python, C++, or any other language on a Raspberry Pi to connect to Wi-Fi OBDII adapter?

Sorry if this is the wrong forum for this but I figured this one had the best chance of anyone knowing

Comment: What you seem to be asking for is paid labor and not a specific question.

Comment: I just want to know if anyone knows where I can find documentation for this, there must be docs somewhere because there are several apps for Android and Linux that can do this using apparently standardized protocols. I just can't find any mention of them anywhere.

Comment: this describes the protocol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498747/car-obdii-wlan-protocol , and this describes how to connect to the obd2 sensor https://www.amazon.ca/review/R5HUE5N2GJ8ZF/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00JQW9NCE&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=3379552011&store=wireless

Comment: That first link was a lot of help. Somewhere in there it mentioned web-sockets. After looking that up I found out I can connect to the port using netcat, and once connected I just have to use the hexadecimal commands. So far that seems to be working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use netcat to open a web-socket port.

```
netcat 192.168.0.10 35000
```

Where 192.168.0.10 is the OBDII adapter's IP address and 3500 is it's port number.

In Python you can connect with the websocket API on PyPI - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to make this work. Had to make a virtual serial port `ttyUSB0` with `socat` on raspbian stretch.

> socat pty,link=/dev/ttyUSB0,waitslave tcp:192.168.0.10:35000&

Then I followed these instructions

http://www.cowfishstudios.com/blog/obd-pi-raspberry-pi-displaying-car-diagnostics-obd-ii-data-on-an-aftermarket-head-unit

python obd_gui.py

Output shown is my VNC screen to raspberry pi 3

[image: python obd_gui]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've been asked to review your answer, and I have just one comment that might improve it: As I read the original question, and then read your answer, it's not quite clear how it relates to the original question. And so I'd suggest that you begin you answer with something along the lines of, "Here's how to connect your RPi to the OBDII adapter in your car:", and then, something along the lines of, "Python is a good language to use to implement the connection...". All up to you, of course, but remember that reader's attention spans are short.